# Print_Server Migration_Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, print-server, migration

After migrating a print server from Windows Server 2008 to 2012, technicians don't have the ability to make changes on end-user workstations (clients). When they click on printer properties, most of the settings are grayed out. Including the ability to select a different driver.

I migrated the server by building a whole new different virtual server, install Windows 2012, install print server role, and exported the printer by using the "Export List" option. Then, I renamed the new print server by giving it the existing print server name and IP address (printserv1). Renamed the old print server and gave it a different IP address (printservex).

Printers are working for the most part. We just had tie up some loose ends.....
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

For some reason my comments aren't showing!!!
So, here it is:
Senshikaze, u were dead on. I compared security groups on both servers and found that our techs were added as admins on the old server.
TheCleaner: there were no errors been generated. Just settings are grayed out.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Windows 2012, but did you check the print server rights? I know this has bitten me in the past on 08 and 03.

Comment: Can you post relevant error messages, rights on the new printer, rights on the new print server, etc.?  The more info you can provide the more likely to get a valid answer.  As it stands currently there's not much for anyone to go on, other than hunches or possibilities.